# How to find Number of Program Headers of a ELF

Tags: linux, elf

I need to find number of program headers of an ELF executable (a.out) without using objdump or readelf. I think it can be done be through hexdump. But i have no idea about it.
Please give me a idea on how to calculate it.

Thanks

Comment: Go and look for documentation on the ELF format yourself.

Comment: I tried it but unable to understand. I am a starter,your little help can help me a lot

Comment: Why are you asking? Did you consider using some library to read the ELF format?

Comment: Actually i need to do this task..I dont know how to use the libraries

Comment: Then learn how to use the libraries. The ELF format is quite complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find number of program headers of an ELF executable (a.out) without using objdump or readelf.

This is a *trivial* thing to do.

Look in `/usr/include/elf.h` for `Elf32_Ehdr` (or `Elf64_Ehdr` if on a 64-bit machine) definition. Compare what you see there with the output from `readelf -h a.out`. That, and the fact every `ELF` binary begins with `Elf{32,64}_Ehdr` is *all* you need.

Your program will be:

- open the `a.out` file
- read `Elf32_Ehdr` (or `Elf64_Ehdr`) from the beginning
- print `.e_phnum`
- exit